# Automated Load test with 100 new users order product at the same time using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load, performance-testing

I have an online order [site](http://dl3.faqdev.com.au). How to Load test with 100 new users order a product at the same time using jmeter(not one user after another. Order with 100 users at the same time).

For order submitting user has to go multiple pages like as Menu > Checkout > Basket > Your Details with email & password > Payment > Confirmation page.
I have tried it by blazeMeter recorder tools for 1 user order process and then save as JMX file and then import it on Jmeter. Finally unable to get a solution.
 I have passed 2-3 days did not get a solution. Could you please advise.

Comment: JMeter could be used to test the endpoints, but not the whole page functionality like button clicks and such... Take a look at [User manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)

Comment: @SBylemans, Thank you. It was very informative

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases you will not be able to replay the recorded script without prior modification.

For example looking into the login page of the site you provided I can see at least [`__RequestVerificationToken`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/) which needs to be [**correlated**](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter)

[image]

So in order to successfully log in you need to build your test plan as follows:

- Open Login Page

  - Extract the `__RequestVerificationToken` using a [JMeter PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- Perform login. In this request you will need to send the variable from the previous step along with your credentials.

---

If you want 100 users to order a product at exactly the same moment - put [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as a child of the relevant HTTP Request sampler and set "Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by" to `100`

Comment: Thanks a lot.After following your point able to log in.Is it need read 100 User data from CSV file and process it to (Menu > Checkout > Basket > Payment > Confirmation page) for successful order.I am a little bit confuse, Please advise.